# is it possible to add TinyMCE accordion in the react version?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

I manage to implement the new version of tinymce 6.5.0 in Thymeleaf. And the only feature that really interest me is the Accordion one.

I've tried to find any information about how  I can implemented this feature in the React version. I saw that the latest react version of Tinymce is 4.3.0 (@tinymce/tinymce-react
)

Is there a way of adding this future to React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Accordion plugin with React as long as TinyMCE is version 6.5 or higher (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/accordion/). The version number of react-tinymce (4.3.0) is irrelevant.

The version number for the [React Component](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react) is different from the version of TinyMCE itself (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/release-notes/).  The component is a thin wrapper around TinyMCE to make it easier to use in an React application.

You can see what version of TinyMCE is on a webpage by entering this into your browser’s JavaScript console:
`tinymce.majorVersion + "." + tinymce.minorVersion`

Or, if you are using the Help plugin, you can check TinyMCE's version by selecting [Help](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/help/) from the menubar, then clicking Version.

Comment: Yes I know that, I can see that. The question is there a way to implement a feature like Accordion on the react version? 

There is no newer version of React Tinymce!!

Or is there a way of combining the Tinymce v6 in with the Editor from tinymce React into a React app?

Comment: You are from tinyland, how is it possible to not know this?
... I took a printscreen and I will make a youtube video about this because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, you can use the Accordion plugin with React as long TinyMCE is version 6.5 or higher (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/accordion/). The version number of react-tinymce (4.3.0) is irrelevant. I'll update the answer to make that more clear